# Show that the set $B = \{a \in \text{closure}(A)| \exists \varepsilon > 0 : (a,a+\varepsilon)\cap A=\emptyset\}$ is at most countable.

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

The set $A$ is a nonempty subset of $\mathbb R$. I *think* $B$ is just the supremum, and therefore countable, but I'm sure that is incorrect.

Comment: $B$ contains more than just the supremum. Hint: If $A=[0,1]\cup [2,3]$, then $B=\{1,3\}$. For the proof suppose $B$ is uncountable and get a contradition.

Comment: The preferred usage is that countable means "finite or countably infinite" so that countable is equivalent to "not uncountable".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that the intervals $(a, a+\epsilon)$ for different $a$'s are disjoint, and each one contains a rational number.

Comment: How would I show that the intervals are disjoint? It's obvious that they would be, but I'm not sure how to put that in math terms. Otherwise, would assigning each a to the rational number in its corresponding interval give a bijection with the rational numbers and therefore show equivalence?

Comment: @Lo12 It would give an _injection into_ the rational numbers (note that $B$ could be finite, for instance), but it still proves countability.

Comment: @Arthur thank you, injection makes more sense.

Comment: To the proposer: Regarding the intervals being disjoint: If $a,a'\in \bar A$ with $a<a',$ and if $e,e'>0$ such that $(a,a+e)\cap (a',a'+e')\ne \phi$ then $a'\in (a,a+e)$ but then $(a,a+e)\cap \bar A\ne \phi$ which implies that $(a,a+e)\cap A\ne \phi.$

Answer (score 0):

Suppose that $a,b\in B$ with $a\neq b$ and let $I_a:=(a,a+\epsilon)$ and $I_b:=(b,b+\delta)$ such that $I_a\cap A=I_b\cap A = \emptyset$ for some $\epsilon,\delta>0$. Assume that $I_a\cap I_b\neq \emptyset$, then wlog $b\in I_a$. Since $b\in\text{closure}(A)$; for any $\eta>0$: $(b-\eta,b+\eta)\cap A\neq \emptyset$ and since $I_a$ is open, there exists a $\eta_0$ such that 
$$I_a\cap A \supseteq (b-\eta_0,b+\eta_0)\cap A \neq \emptyset.\quad[\text{Thunderbolt}]$$